# vs2015 ctp6 error at create new project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ctp

I'm using [Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-ctp-vs.aspx).
When I click <kbd>New Project...</kbd>, I get an error message:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Visual Studio does not crash, but the template choice dialog doesn't appear.
If I reinstall (all vs2015...) the problem is solved, but only for two days or so...

I know this is beta software, but anyway I really enjoy the improvements, I would be happy if anybody has any idea why this is happening or a shorter time resolution than the overall installation.

Comment: @jessehouwing thank! its work! (delete all in `%appdata%\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`. iwm use resharper, but disabled, and the problem persists).

Comment: There is probably another extension being loaded that ships with older versions of the Visual Studio assemblies. Did you install anything from the Visual Studio gallery?

Comment: as I recall nothing... but not sure.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I have seen, but there are a few that are there from the installation. see http://i.imgur.com/wJGUX1h.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@jessehouwing's comment it was the solution for me.
I deleted the entire contents of this folder:

> %AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

(you can delete it herself). And it works great.
Thanks to @jessehouwing's and all ..

TIP: for delete form PowerShell type:

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force ($env:APPDATA +  "\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache")
```